# Adding gesture builder to my app?

Tags: android

Building gestures in advance and forcing the user to use them is ok, but what would be great is if the end user could define their own gestures for my application.  Once great example that does this is the Dolphin web browser.

Does anyone have any good links to this or where one can locate the source code to the gesture builder app that comes in the emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Does anyone have any good links to this or where one can locate the source code to the gesture builder app that comes in the emulator?

That sample is in the SDK folder.

Comment: Wow I feel silly and that is exactly where that sample app is!